# Express $T:\Bbb E^2 \rightarrow \Bbb E^2$ defined in coordinates by $T(\mathbf x)=A\mathbf x+\mathbf b$ in the form $T=Rot(P, \theta)$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

Given are:

-$\mathbf b$ is a translation vector in the plane.

-Point $P \in \Bbb E^2$ such that $Rot(O, \theta)(P)=Trans(-\mathbf x)(P$).

-MatrixA= \begin{bmatrix}cos\theta&-sin\theta\\sin\theta&cos\theta\end{bmatrix}

Express the motion $T:\Bbb E^2 \rightarrow \Bbb E^2$ defined in coordinates by $T(\mathbf x)=A\mathbf x+\mathbf b$ in the form $T=Rot(P, \theta)$

So far I've just drawn the picture of $Rot(O, \theta)(P)=Trans(-\mathbf x)(P$).

Comment: You may use `\mathbf x` for bold-face mathematical symbol $\mathbf x$.

Comment: It's probably better to sorted out on your own, since it's not something subtle and every book of mathematics of undegrad level contains your question. Try it out once, and if you don't understand it come over again :)

Comment: I might not understand your notations, but if $A$ is the identity matrix then $T$ is just the translation by $\mathbf b$, which cannot be a rotation. Once again, I might be misinterpreting your notations, so maybe it's better to explicitly state what you understand by $Rot$ and $Trans$.